# Error creating SQLite table after DROP

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've got about 50 devices running my application. Some users expirience a strange error (not all):

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: points (code 1)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForCursorWindow(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java:840)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:836)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:143)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:197)
at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToNext(AbstractCursor.java:245)
at kgk_logic.Manager.reloadPoints(Manager.java:67)
at mobile.WorkActivity$WHandler.handleMessage(WorkActivity.java:544)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5124)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:783)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:550)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The logic is: once in 15 mins device checks its location and compares with remote bd data/ If device in specific radius - server returns a list of points (just coords). These points go to the SQLTable "points", but before that previus points table is dropped and new one created with new fresh data:

```
DB db = DB.getInstance(KGKMobile.getAppContext());
SQLiteDatabase wdb = db.getWritableDatabase();
wdb.execSQL(String.format("DROP TABLE %s", DB.POINTS_TABLE));
db.createPointsTable(wdb);

for (KGKPoint point : WorkActivity.getManager().getPoints()) {
    wdb.insert(DB.POINTS_TABLE, null, point.getCV());
}
```

Method `createPointsTable()` contains only one query:

```
execSQL(String.format("CREATE TABLE %s (id integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, name TEXT NOT NULL, lat real NOT NULL, lng real NOT NULL, code TEXT )", "points"));
```

My bet - table dropped but not created properly. But i don't know why. Or maybe there is another reason?

Comment: Is there any possibility that drop a table is called before creating that table?

Comment: Is there any possibility that `Manager.reloadPoints()` is called before the table created? Do you see anything common between users with the issue (device, Android version)?

Comment: As we see in code - drop occurs just before create. If you mean otherwise - create before drop - nope, all associated operations run on same thread

Comment: Devices, that experience this error - are same as mine. And my device runs app ok, with no exceptions. Or maybe i can't reproduce the error algorythm, but i have no direct contact with users - only Acralyzer panel(

Comment: Do you need to drop table before inserting new data? Can you just erase all the data instead?

Comment: good is to delete all data instead of dropping and creating table. From the operation order it should not give any error ... only possible cause is table creation is taking fraction of moments more after create code is executed. So when your insert code is executing ... your table is yet not created. put a try-catch and you will notice some of the rows will be inserted

Comment: Performed stress-test - the same operation with 100 inserts per second with droppping and creating - the real load is way lower - no exceptions detected. I think i will try to replace drop/create with "truncate"... I think. there can be problems with database version.

Comment: Since it only happens on some users, my bet is it is a race condition -- occasionally, the table won't have finished dropping before attempting to create.